# refactoring spring boot application to use npm modules

Tags: spring-boot, npm

I had a spring boot application referencing JS files from resources/static folder. I installed node modules in that application in the root of the project. Can I load `npm` downloaded modules in java spring boot application ? How shall I reference the JS libraries in html files of the application ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but my guess is that you should put the `node_modules` folder in the `src/main/resources/static` folder (probably by moving your `package.json` there as well). Alternatively take a look at [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/)  which allow you to generate a JAR file based on an npm package.

Comment: yes you are correct i did that and asked the same.